# Ruby on Rails join two table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two tables and they looks like

```
listing1: PID:String Description:String 

listing2: Pid:String Category:String
```

I want to join these two table and display them in view

I tried to use the statement in my controller:

```
@tmp = Listing1.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN listing2s ON listing1s.PID = listing2s.Pid')

@next = @tmp.where("listing2s.Category = 'toy'")
```

Now I have two problem:

1. I can't access Listing2 attribute in my view. `@tmp.Description` is working but `@tmp.Category` failed and throw unknown method error
2. In controller `@next = @tmp.where("listing2s.Category = 'toy'")` will not effect and I have to make it as  `@next = Listing1.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN listing2s ON listing1s.PID = listing2s.Pid').where("listing2s.Category = 'toy'")`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yaofei,

First,"@tmp.Category failed" cause @tmp is an array,"@tmp.fisrt.Category" will be ok.

Second,the fail reason is the same as first,if you won't to write like that,you can use rails's scope,it really make the code clean and tidy.see:

```
scope :toy, -> { listing2s.Category = 'toy' }
scope :join_listing2_with_pid, -> { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN listing2s ON listing1s.PID = listing2s.Pid') }
```

Finally,you can use scope like that:

```
@tmp = Listing1.join_listing2_with_pid
@next = Listing1.join_listing2_with_pid.toy
```

Comment: Thanks Troy. The scope in rails solve my second question. However I still have problem to display the attribute in my view. As you mentioned, I use @tmp.fisrt.Category and it shows me undefined methond "category" for #<Listing1:0*********>. It seems I can only access attributes in listing1 not for listing2. tmp.first.PID and tmp.first.discription works fine. tmp.first.Pid and tmp.first.Category fails

Comment: Oh,i'm sorry for forgeting to ask you what relationship is between Listing1 and Listing2?At the same time,i must to tell you an nice way to debug the code: rails console!you can perform the above code in it,and it'll always show you the result timely.